# Why does 100% width on inputfield/textfield overlap containing div?

Tags: html, css, input-field

Why does 100% width on an inputfield/textfield overlap the containing div?

http://jsfiddle.net/lassebjensen/Uujck/3/

Css:

```
.red-div-400px{
    background-color:red;
    width:400px
}

.input{
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 28px;
}
```

Html:

```
<div class="red-div-400px">
E-mail  
<input  class="input" type="text">
</div>
```

This code below fixes the problem but what causes the overlap? Why can you not set the width of the textfield to 100%?

```
 width: 100%;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
```

Kind Regards

Comment: It's the padding of the input that causes this, and its borders. See the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uujck/4/). If you inspect the input, you will see it don't overlap anymore.

Comment: just as Brewal said: here the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Uujck/8/

Comment: It's just how the `box model` works, So width at 100% + padding means that the size of the input will be over `100% `wide. The `CSS3` `box-sizing` property adds the padding inside the element, thus it doesn't increase the overall width.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The input field's width includes the `padding` and any `border` set, therefore 100% + 1px padding + 2px border = overlap.

The `box-sizing` fixes this because it ensures the rendered input field is the specified width.

Answer (score 3):

You are forgetting the 2px borders (for each side).

You can use CSS3 Calc to avoid this problem:

```
width: calc(100% - 4px);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Uujck/6/

To see which browser supports it, refer to *CanIUse* or similar sites: http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc

Comment: I didn't know we could do that. Is `calc` supported by all browsers ?

Comment: If anyone's interested: **[Calc Support](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc)** vs **[Box-Sizing support](http://caniuse.com/#search=box-sizing)**

Comment: Calc isn't as supported. Therefore, the better solution would be box-sizing. Also you'd have to adjust this code if you ever change the padding and/or border-size

Answer (score 2):

It's the padding of the input that causes this, and its borders. See the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uujck/4/). If you inspect the input, you will see it don't overlap anymore :

```
.input 
{
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 28px;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
}
```